# Discrepency regarding term in the Wigner Characteristic Function

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

Consider the quantum characteristic function, $$
\chi_\rho(\mathbf{s})=\operatorname{tr}\{\hat{\rho} \hat{D}(\mathbf{s})\}
$$
The displacement operator is defined to be: $$
\hat{D}(\mathbf{r})=\exp \left[\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2} \hat{\mathbf{R}}^T \Omega \mathbf{r}\right]
$$
where $ \hat{\mathbf{R}} $ is defined to be a row vector containing the quadrature operators, with each defined as:
$$
\hat{X}=\sqrt{\frac{2 m w}{\hbar}} \hat{q} ;     \hat{P}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\hbar m w}} \hat{p}
$$
and $ \mathbf{r} = (x, p)^T $, where $x$ and $p$ are eigenvalues of the quadrature operators above. This concept of the vector $ \hat{\mathbf{R}} $ having the quadrature operators as components is seen in various [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234v1).

But I've also seen [StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/684334/reconciling-two-descriptions-of-the-wigner-function) articles on Wigner functions where the characteristic function is defined such that, in the displacement operator, $ \hat{\mathbf{R}} $ is defined to be a row vector containing only the position and momentum operators, instead of the quadrature components.

While I do understand that there's just a multiple of a constant difference between the quadrature operators and the position/momentum operators, won't this make the above two Wigner functions not equivalent?

Comment: Hi Pratham Hullamballi. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Comment: The change in dimensions due to the additional constants does not affect the mathematical definition of a Wigner function. In fact Wigner functions are often used in contexts (such as in quantum optics) where the associations of the quadrature operators with the position and momentum operators are not valid.

Comment: @flippiefanus could you emphasise why change in dimension from additional constants doesn't effect the Wigner function?